# Does PhoneGap support In-App Purchase?

Tags: javascript, iphone, app-store, cordova, in-app-purchase

Has anyone used [David Orchard's fork](https://github.com/DavidOrchard/phonegap-iphone) for in-app purchases with PhoneGap? It hasn't been updated in over a year. According to this [thread](http://help.urbanairship.com/discussions/questions/51-in-app-purchases-using-phonegap) Urban Airship can't help yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah! I just needed to look a bit harder, this PhoneGap plugin should work perfectly. I'll comment here how well it works with Urban Airship.

[https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager)

Comment: I was just going to suggest that one :)

Comment: Did it work well? Did you make use of another solution? I'd like to have an Idea, if phoneGap might be a tool for me when I need inApp purchase support.

Comment: The latest unofficial plugin (from which the official is forked) seems to be at: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager

Comment: Just another ping, to see if you could report any progress with this :)

Comment: Works perfectly for me on 2.0; the only thing I had to change was to remove CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK in InAppPurchaseManager.h

Comment: Do you know if there is an android version of this?
I have found a few plugins for android and iPhone but really I would like to try and keep both iPhone and android as close as possible (using the same plugin).

Comment: Android phonegap plugin: https://github.com/poiuytrez/phonegap-plugins/tree/billingPlugin/Android/InAppBilling.
Read the following discussion to overcome the only errors that I encountered during implementation: https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/issues/52

Comment: link seems to be broken

Answer (score 4):

The [phonegap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager) suggested by daniellmb works well. Please keep the following in mind

1. CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK in InAppPurchaseManager.h, remove all the code around that. You will run into 'CDVPlugin.h' file not found in inAppPurchaseManager.h, this is how both import should look

   ```
   #import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
   #import <Cordova/NSData+Base64.h>
   ```
2. If you get the errror Plugin 'InAppPurchaseManager' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist. You have to add the following to Cordova.plist

   ```
   <key>InAppPurchaseManager</key>
   <string>InAppPurchaseManager</string>
   ```