# In app purchases on iPhone / Android / WP7 using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any cross-platform in app purchase solution for PhoneGap based apps? I've seen a PayPal plugin for Android/iOS (https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/PayPalPlugin/README.md).

But does that plugin "break the ios and android rules"? I mean, with paypal we skip the 30% that goes to apple and google, is that correct? Isn't that a risk for the iphone app certification process?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679352/does-phonegap-support-in-app-purchase). And I'd say the answer is **yes**, there are solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will reject this, you can only use Apple's IAP system in iOS apps.
For android there aren't rules like these so you will be fine.

Comment: is there any alternative for apple while using phonegap?

Comment: I don't use PhoneGap, but I'm sure that Apple will reject any other in app purchases other then the one they provide. Can't imagine that the iOS iap isn't available in PhoneGap.