# In app purchase using phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cordova, in-app-purchase

I am having an idea to develop an iphone app using phonegap with ability to provide in app purchase functionality.

So I would like to know that is that possible to implemend itunes in app purchase using phonegap

Please help and thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PhoneGap support In-App Purchase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679352/does-phonegap-support-in-app-purchase)

Answer (score 0):

The Phonegap tools page mentions Urbain Airship as making it easy to "integrate ... in app purchase to your applications." See http://urbanairship.com

As an alternative middleware for iOS, consider Corona (http://anscamobile.com), which has in-app purchasing included.

Answer (score 0):

Surely its possible. I have implemented it in my iOS game development [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tapgem/id600119102?mt=8)

Both Apple Consumable and Non-consumable In App purchases work perfect.
You can download the In App Purchase plugin for iOS [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager)